# variation of goldbach

Tags: number-theory, elementary-number-theory, goldbachs-conjecture

I am observing that every even number is the difference of two primes. It appears to be true for a number of numbers (doesn't mean it is true, I know).

Question: Anyone know more on this?

Thanks

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Goldberg_Variations

Comment: Oh, GoldBach. Never mind.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is an open problem [see here](http://primes.utm.edu/notes/conjectures/).

It is a much weaker version of the well known Polignac conjecture.